# pandoc problem with unicode

Tags: macos, pdf, font, open-source, markdown

On MacOS 12.6.9, I try to convert a Markdown file to PDF. For this, I'm using `pandoc 3.1.2`, installed with Homebrew. There are problems converting the characters `∧` and `∨`, which I use for expressing logical formulas. For instance, with this file `utf.md`

```
X ∧ Y ∨ Z
```

which in hex (`xxd utf.md`) would be

```
5820 e288 a720 5920 e288 a820 5a0a 0a
```

and `LANG` being set to `en_GB.UTF-8`, the command `pandoc -s -o utf.pdf utf.md` produces the error message

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ∧ (U+2227)
           not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Googling for the problem, I found the suggestion to use *xelatex* as LaTeX engine. So I tried

```
pandoc -s --pdf-engine=xelatex -o utf.pdf utf.md
```

This resulted in

```
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ∧ (U+2227) (U+2227) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ∨ (U+2228) (U+2228) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
```

and, not surprisingly, the generated pdf file did not include those two characters. I conclude that the font (*lmroman10-regular*) does not include glyphs for these characters.

No my question is: What font would be suitable here, and how do I specify that font for `pandoc`?

**UPDATE**

About the font reported by Pandoc (*lmroman10*): I looked at the fonts installed on my Mac (using the the application *Font Book*), and there is no font named *lmroman*, so I'm puzzled where pandoc gets this font from.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to upgrade your brew packages with `brew upgrade` - this
will be useful for a newer version of pandoc, since, starting with May 2022
in Markdown you can insert inline expressions with `$ $` or block expressions
with `$$ $$`. Instead of the utf symbols used by you, try the LaTeX
symbols `\lor` and `\land` for logical expressions, so your math
expression should be `$ X \land Y \lor Z $`.

As for fonts, I assume you have LaTeX installed, so the Latin modern fonts are in e.g.
`/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm`.

The above expression rendered in .pdf:

[image]

You should check out the pandoc version (mine is 3.1.7 on Ventura). Please
note I did not choose/set any LaTeX font - what you see is the pandoc work. This is achieved with `katex` or `mathjax` at export stage.
Also, the export to `html` is easy, with this command:
`--from=markdown --to=html5  --standalone --katex --template=elegant_bootstrap_menu.html`
(choose a html template of your own) The result:

[image]

Comment: Use xelatex engine, as you discovered. In my example I changed the order of logical operations, this should not be problem.

Comment: I have installed _pandoc_ this year in june, so it should be pretty new. I would rather not like putting latex code directly into my Markdown document, because the same base document is supposed to be used for generating HTML as well. Isn't there a suitable font, which I can use with _xelatex_, which already contains these characters?

Comment: I had meanwhile time to turn to this problem again. Actually, output to HTML is not a problem;  I have solved the HTML part. My problem is PDF. I have upgraded pandoc to 3.1.8 now. The directory `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm` does not exist on my Mac.  I see a directory `/usr/local/texlive/2023basic/texmf-var`. Not knowing any LaTeX, I would be grateful if you could let me know what else I need to generate my PDF. Current command is `pandoc -s --pdf-engine=xelatex`.

Comment: I have full 2022 texlive distribution, you seem to have the 2023 version, so the differences in paths. My command to get .pdf is ```pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V documentclass=scrarticle -V geometry:a4paper -V geometry:margin=2cm -V geometry:nohead --listings my-file.md -o my-file.pdf``` and all is OK. I think the problem may be the mode you typed unicode - in my case I use Unicode Hex Input keyboard, works also with your original codes U+2227/2228.

Comment: My input file is UTF-8 encoded, so the characters are presented there just as this encoding specifies. BTW, what is the `documentclass` used for? Do I need this too?

Comment: Exporting to .pdf is done through an intermediary step with LaTeX, which uses document class to specify the kind of target (article, book). Not needed, and in this case it is used an pandoc default template (article).